# NSURL path not functioning as expected despite encoding spaces for fileWithUrlPath:

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, nsurl

I'm implementing a simple button-sound interface for a toy project.  There are multiple buttons, with individual sounds assigned to each button.  I accomplish this all within the fooViewController.{h,m} with the 'tag' attribute of each UIButton like so:

```
B0.tag = 0;
B1.tag = 1;
...
```

I also have an array of sound files, which I hold inside an array of strings, populated as follows:

```
sounds[0] = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"caf"];
sounds[1] = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bar" ofType:@"caf"];
...
```

Now when a button Touch Up Inside event is triggered, the following method fires:

```
-(IBAction)playSoundClip:(id)sender {

    if(sounds[[sender tag]] != nil) {
        NSError *error;        
        NSString *temp = [sounds[[sender tag]]   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        AVAudioPlayer *av = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:temp] error:&error];

        [av play]
    }
}
```

I always receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.  When I print out the strings, they are in tact, and as can be expected.. a few spaces, which I thought would be taken care of by the string encoding ^above.

Comment: Can you `NSLog([error description])`? That might give more insight to the problem.

Comment: Also log the temp string please and let us know what you get.

Comment: Hi Richard/Evan, thank you for your suggestions.  It seems that when I try an get any debug output from the playSoundClip: method, I am getting undefined results, mostly resulting in a crash - sometimes a hang.  This might add credence to some of the other suggestions that the NSString array contents are being deallocated.  Was unaware that that happened across methods, despite the NSString array being in my class interface.  So basically I am indexing an array filled with garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating the `C` array with autoreleased objects. Since you are not taking ownership of the objects, they would have been released soon after assignment.

My recommendation is to use an `NSArray` instance to hold your paths. It will automatically retain them when you add the path.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but he says his strings are "in tact" so I assume that means his NSString temp.  From that point on, the {C} array is irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: @Richard It would be clearer if we know when he printed the strings. If he did it in the method where he assigns the values, then they will show up. But in the `playSoundClip:` method, the `C` array will be holding pointers to deallocated objects.

Comment: Hi guys, I think I should have re-checked my facts. The strings are in tact from when I set them up in the array - I can index the array and pull out the resource paths, etc.  Everything looked peachy from that point of view.  The NSString *sounds[8] array is declared in my class implementation, but if Deepak is right, then it means I need to investigate why the NSString array is deallocated across method boundaries.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: All, in closing, I converted to using an NSArray, and was able to complete this stage of development.  Previously I was seeing non-deterministic output due to garbage in the NSString array; as suggested by Deepak, this was due to the contents being autoreleased soon after they were assigned.  Thanks to all for your inputs!

Comment: @swisscheese If you wished to use the `C` array, you will have to do manual memory management. Assigning would require you to send `retain` message, reassigning would involve `release`-ing the old value and `retain`ing the new value. And in `dealloc`, you should `release` them. `NSArray` takes this responsibility off, among other things, from our hands. @Richard I guess that resolves the confusion. :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate NSError *error:

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

Comment: No, you don't. The address of `error` is passed to the `AVAudioPlayer` initialization so that it gets "populated" with an `NSError` object if an error occurs.

Comment: You should at least set it to nil: `NSError *error = nil`. You should not allocate it as Even noted, then you are just leaking.

Comment: Thanks guys, your advice has been taken onboard.